# Retrieving Auto Increment Number from Database and Updating Child rows based on that

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, parent-child, ado

I have an issue with updating parent and child rows that when I insert a new parent row and I retrieve a new ID from the database I need to update the child rows parentId based on that but it didn't because I think I'm using merge method. to reflect the changes in the main datatable.

I tried to create a simple example to explain my issue and the approach I'm using

here is the database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ParentTable
(  
  ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
  ParentName varchar(100)  
)   



CREATE TABLE ChildTable  
(  
  ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
  ParentId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ParentTable(id) ,
  ChildName varchar(100)  
)   


GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_INSERT_ParentTable] @ParentName NVarChar(100) , @GetScopeIdentity SmallInt = 0 OUTPUT AS 
BEGIN
   SET
      NOCOUNT 
      ON 
      INSERT INTO ParentTable (ParentName) VALUES ( @ParentName);

      SET @GetScopeIdentity = SCOPE_IDENTITY() RETURN @GetScopeIdentity 
END



GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_INSERT_ChildTable] @ParentId int, @ChildName NVarChar(100) , @GetScopeIdentity SmallInt = 0 OUTPUT AS 
BEGIN
   SET
      NOCOUNT 
      ON 
      INSERT INTO ChildTable(ParentId,ChildName) VALUES ( @ParentId,@ChildName);

      SET @GetScopeIdentity = SCOPE_IDENTITY() RETURN @GetScopeIdentity 
END


-- resetting tables 
TRUNCATE TABLE ChildTable;
DELETE FROM ParentTable;
DBCC CHECKIDENT (ParentTable, RESEED, 0);


INSERT INTO ParentTable (ParentName) VALUES ('Parent 1');
INSERT INTO ParentTable (ParentName) VALUES ('Parent 2');

INSERT INTO ChildTable(ParentId,ChildName) VALUES (1,'Child 1');
INSERT INTO ChildTable(ParentId,ChildName) VALUES (1,'Child 2');

INSERT INTO ChildTable(ParentId,ChildName) VALUES (2,'Child 3');
INSERT INTO ChildTable(ParentId,ChildName) VALUES (2,'Child 4');
```

and here is the code I'm using :

```
    private static readonly string ConnectionString = "Server=.;Database=DbTest;User Id=sa;Password=;";

    private static void AddParentRowFromDatabase()
    {
        using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        using SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ParentTable (ParentName) VALUES (@ParentName);";
        command.Parameters.Add("@ParentName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

        sqlConnection.Open();

        // this row id should be now 3 because by default we are adding only two parent 
        // but notice that the dataset and DataTable doesn't know that we added this row 
        command.Parameters["@ParentName"].Value = "Added From Database Parent.";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        var dataset = new DataSet();

        // Creating ParentTable Adapter and preparing its InsertCommand 
        var parentTableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Id, ParentName from ParentTable", connection)
        {
            MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey,
            AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false
        };
        parentTableAdapter.RowUpdated += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.StatementType != StatementType.Insert) return;
            e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
        };

        var parentInsertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_INSERT_ParentTable", connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};
        parentInsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentName", SqlDbType.NVarChar) {SourceColumn = "ParentName"});
        parentInsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GetScopeIdentity", SqlDbType.Int) {SourceColumn = "Id", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output});
        parentInsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
        parentTableAdapter.InsertCommand = parentInsertCommand;
        // Here we just retrieve the structure as my real project and later I call fill method when I need it
        parentTableAdapter.FillSchema(dataset, SchemaType.Mapped, "ParentTable");

        // Creating ChildTable Adapter and preparing its InsertCommand 
        var childTableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Id, ParentId, ChildName from ChildTable", connection)
        {
            MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey,
            AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false
        };
        childTableAdapter.RowUpdated += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.StatementType != StatementType.Insert) return;
            e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
        };

        var childInsertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_INSERT_ChildTable", connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};
        childInsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentId", SqlDbType.Int) {SourceColumn = "ParentId"});
        childInsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChildName", SqlDbType.NVarChar) {SourceColumn = "ChildName"});
        childInsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GetScopeIdentity", SqlDbType.Int) {SourceColumn = "Id", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output});
        childInsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
        childTableAdapter.InsertCommand = childInsertCommand;
        // Here we just retrieve the structure as my real project and later I call fill method when I need it
        childTableAdapter.FillSchema(dataset, SchemaType.Mapped, "ChildTable");

        // Here we create DataRelation and passing true for creating constraints 
        var dataRelation = new DataRelation("ParentTable:ChildTable", dataset.Tables["ParentTable"].Columns["ID"], dataset.Tables["ChildTable"].Columns["ParentId"], true);
        dataset.Relations.Add(dataRelation);

        // So wherever id in parent changes the child rows also changes 
        dataRelation.ChildKeyConstraint.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade;

        // Now we fill the tables from database 
        parentTableAdapter.Fill(dataset, "ParentTable");
        childTableAdapter.Fill(dataset, "ChildTable");

        Console.WriteLine("Dumping ParentTable content");
        Print_results(dataset.Tables["ParentTable"]);

        Console.WriteLine("Dumping ChildTable content");
        Print_results(dataset.Tables["ChildTable"]);

        Console.ReadLine();

        // Now lets act like we are on another pc and add some rows to the parentTable some our parentTable object doesn't know the real current row id
        Console.WriteLine("Adding some data from database.");
        AddParentRowFromDatabase(); // here we adding only one row it's id should be 3

        // Now lets add a parent with child rows using our adapters 
        DataRow newParentRow = dataset.Tables["ParentTable"].NewRow();
        newParentRow["ParentName"] = "Parent Added from DataAdapter";
        dataset.Tables["ParentTable"].Rows.Add(newParentRow);

        // adding child rows 
        // child 1
        DataRow newChildRow1 = dataset.Tables["ChildTable"].NewRow();
        newChildRow1["ParentId"] = newParentRow["ID"];
        newChildRow1["ChildName"] = "Child Added from DataAdapter 1 should be linked with parentId 4";
        // child 2
        DataRow newChildRow2 = dataset.Tables["ChildTable"].NewRow();
        newChildRow2["ParentId"] = newParentRow["ID"];
        newChildRow2["ChildName"] = "Child Added from DataAdapter 2 should be linked with parentid 4";

        dataset.Tables["ChildTable"].Rows.Add(newChildRow1);
        dataset.Tables["ChildTable"].Rows.Add(newChildRow2);

        // now lets review what we got 
        // the new added parent Id in the memory is 3 
        // but when we use the adapter it should update the row and change the id value to 4 because there is a row with id 3 
        // what I need after that to update the child rows ParentId column with the new retrieved id value 

        DataTable parentTableChanges = dataset.Tables["ParentTable"].GetChanges();

        DataTable childTableChanges = dataset.Tables["ChildTable"].GetChanges();

        parentTableAdapter.Update(parentTableChanges);

        dataset.Tables["ParentTable"].Merge(parentTableChanges); // merge updated id to the parent table

        childTableAdapter.Update(childTableChanges);

        dataset.Tables["ChildTable"].Merge(childTableChanges); // merge updated id to the parent table

        // now if we dump child rows we should see the new added childs but with the new retreived ParentId which is 4 

        Print_results(dataset.Tables["ParentTable"]);

        Print_results(dataset.Tables["ChildTable"]);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Print_results(DataTable data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        var colWidths = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write(col.ColumnName);
            int maxLabelSize = data.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                .Select(m => (m.Field<object>(col.ColumnName)?.ToString() ?? "").Length)
                .OrderByDescending(m => m).FirstOrDefault();

            colWidths.Add(col.ColumnName, maxLabelSize);
            for (var i = 0; i < maxLabelSize - col.ColumnName.Length + 10; i++) Console.Write(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in data.Rows)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < dataRow.ItemArray.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(dataRow.ItemArray[j]);
                for (var i = 0; i < colWidths[data.Columns[j].ColumnName] - dataRow.ItemArray[j].ToString().Length + 10; i++) Console.Write(" ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End of the table.\n\n");
    }
```

I hope I was clear. Does anyone know a better approach?

Thanks for help

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefix is **reserved** by Microsoft for **S**pecial **P**rocedures, and should *not* be used for user objects. `RETURN` is also used to define the success status of a procedure, `0` meaning success and anything else failure. It shouldn't *really* be used for returning values like `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Comment: Sorry for that. You're 100% right. This is only for explaining my issue. but thanks for sharing your knowledge with me

Comment: Use `OUTPUT` parameters as they are meant to. By the way, you could also `SELECT @GetScopeIdentity` and then use `ExecuteScalar()` on the C# side. And be aware that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` type is decimal, so make sure you always convert it, or store it in an `int` variable as you are doing now.

Comment: Further points: You should really specify `varchar` parameter lengths on the C# side. If you are doing a batch insert, you can get all the IDs with `OUTPUT inserted.ID`

Comment: Thanks for the great advice, but this is only an example that I just created to demonstrate my problem in my project. I can't bring my main project because it's very big. I have to use the same approach here. my problem is how to update child rows parentId value with the new retrieved id without looping throw them and assign the value manually. I'm asking why the DataRelation that I created doesn't take care of updating the child rows as it should